# TinyDuino radio connection

Tags: arduino-nano, wireless

I am currently running a project with 2 TinyDuinos and 2 TinyShields 433MHz Radio (SI4432) in order to pass 3 axes (x , y ,z) from one to the other from long distance.

I have tried

- to concat the axes as one string and send the string,
- to send an array like `string axes = { x , y , z }` to the
  receiver (of course the variables are already defined),
- send only one string. In this case I have only the first 2 letters of the string. For example if the string was `string first = "456"` , I would get `"45"` on the receiver

The Radio shield's examples uses uint8_t type and arrays to send and receive the data, I have already tried to cast the string to char* and then to uint8_t and nothing different happens. Maybe I am missing something.

Below there are my code screen shots. I will put 2 links for the examples of the transmitter and the receiver I got some code from

Similar Project : https://tinycircuits.com/blogs/learn/121634375-football-play-calling-watch-tutorial

Radio Shield Page: https://tinycircuits.com/products/433mhz-long-range-radio-tinyshield

TinyDuino Main Shield : https://tinycircuits.com/collections/all/products/tinyduino-processor-board

### Code Screenshots

[image: Transmitter code]

[image: Receiver code]

[image: Output from Receiver]

Comment: Please add the code in your question, don't use images/screenshots.  This allows easier editing by others and more crucially helps the search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of thing you need to craft a packet to contain your data. The best method is to use a *struct*.

```
struct coords {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

Then you can define a variable from it:

```
struct coords myCoords;
```

And set individual values:

```
myCoords.x = 23;
myCoords.y = 180;
myCoords.z = -3817;
```

Now you can cast it to whatever type you need for sending:

```
manager.sendtoWait((uint8_t *)&myCoords, sizeof(struct coords), SERVER_ADDRESS);
```

Receiving is done in much the same way:

```
struct coords recCoords;
uint8_t len = sizeof(struct coords);
uint8_t from;

if (manager.recvfromAck((uint8_t *)&recCoords, &len, &from)) {
    Serial.print("X = ");
    Serial.println(recCoords.x); 
    Serial.print("Y = ");
    Serial.println(recCoords.y); 
    Serial.print("Z = ");
    Serial.println(recCoords.z); 
}
```

---

In future please *post your actual code*, not pictures of your code. It makes it a real pain having to keep scrolling up and manually typing in bits of your code rather than being able to copy-and-paste a couple of lines.